# How to make iCal event repeat based on Chinese calendar?

Tags: calendar, ical

My MacBook Pro running Yosemite has Finder in Simplified Chinese and iCal is set to show Chinese calendar dates next to the Gregorian calendar dates.

I know how to make events repeat every year on a certain Gregorian calendar date but how can I make events repeat every year on a certain Chinese calendar date (for example, for major Chinese festivals)?

Comment: If you can't find a way, there are probably online calendars that you can subscribe to that list all the Chinese festivals.

Answer (score 1):

iCal (actually now Calendar.app) is strictly a Gregorian calendar. It shows Chinese dates as a matter of convenience, but it does not actually operate on the Chinese calendar system.